# Can't get div to expand height to include content inside

Tags: css, height

I can't figure out how to get the height of my middle-container div to expand to fit the data inside. I'm getting lost in suggestions like height:100%, etc. Anyone figure out what css I need to add to fix the following:

http://www.tippycanoetoo.com/pillows-rugs-throws.html

http://www.tippycanoetoo.com/emma-20-5-square-throw-pillow-1.html

(It appears fine in Firefox & IE7, but not Chrome, Safari, & IE8 - it temporarily is fine in IE8 b/c I set the compatibility mode to IE7 in the head.)

Comment: -1: If this has a minimum working example this would be useful after it helped you. But because it just has a link, that has now broken. It is fairly useless. (Leave a comment when/if it is fixed and I will retract the downvote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to `.middle-container` or `.middle`

See [clearing floats](http://work.arounds.org/clearing-floats/) for an explanation